# Play two sounds simultaneusly

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to play two sounds at the same time?

I know that `SoundPlayer` isn't able to do this.
I can't use `SoundEffect` as I believe it's only part of XNA.

The two required sounds will be called at unknown and random times.  The sound needs to be be controlled after it is played. i.e., the sound must be able to be stopped before it has finished playing.

Comment: What environment? ASP.NET/web? WinForms? WPF Desktop? Silverlight?

Comment: Hi, It's for a windows form application!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Reference `PresentationCore` and `WindowsBase` and try this...

```
var p1 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
p1.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\windows\media\tada.wav"));
p1.Play();

// this sleep is here just so you can distinguish the two sounds playing simultaneously
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

var p2 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
p2.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\windows\media\tada.wav"));
p2.Play();
```

**EDIT**
I received a downvote probably because at first glance this looks like it will play the second sound after the first is finished. It doesn't, they are played by windows asynchronously. The sleep is there so if you test this code verbatim you can hear the sounds play together, it wouldn't be noticeable without the delay since they are the same sound.

This code demonstrates the two sounds playing on separate threads on top of each other, which is sort of pointless since the playback doesn't block anyway

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
        var c = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
        c.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\windows\media\tada.wav"));
        c.Play();
    }).Start();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
        var c = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
        c.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\windows\media\tada.wav"));
        c.Play();
    }).Start();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.stop.aspx
The class also has the control you need to stop playback

Comment: out of interest I tried using the new Thread code, which runs, but nothing plays... even though it works fine using the first code block. Does Audio have to happen in the main thread?

Comment: This answer could do with updating. Particularly now we have TPL `Task`

Comment: @lex Make sure the MediaPlayer isn't being disposed before/while its playing. That's what got me.

Answer (score 8):

The "MediaPlayer" object will not let you play two sounds at once, even if you create two instances.  You will need to bring in the native windows API "mciSendString".

```
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    static extern Int32 mciSendString(string command, StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize, IntPtr hwndCallback);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mciSendString(@"open C:\Users\Jono\Desktop\applause.wav type waveaudio alias applause", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        mciSendString(@"play applause", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        mciSendString(@"open C:\Users\Jono\Desktop\foghorn.wav type waveaudio alias foghorn", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        mciSendString(@"play foghorn", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check `PlaySound` method here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909766.aspx, and its flag `SND_ASYNC` .

Comment: PlaySound can't play two sounds at the same time, even if you do use async flag.  You might be able to get this to work by having two seperate threads both calling PlaySound synchronously.

Comment: You just call it to times in a row, when using that flag the method will exit immediately and second one will start.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
Hi,
I was developing a WP8 App and i needed multiple sounds to play simultaneously, the solutions mentioned above didnt work for me, So i used the XNA framwork. here is the link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff842408.aspx

and then play ur sound files like this...

```
SoundEffect Sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/Sounds/wav/sound.wav", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
Sound.Play();
```

For looping...

```
SoundEffectInstance Sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/Sounds/wav/sound.wav", UriKind.Relative)).Stream).CreateInstance();
Sound.IsLooped = true;
Sound.Play();
```

Note: the files must be in ".wav" (PCM, 8 or 16-bit, 8KHz to 48KHz, mono or stereo) format

Answer (score 0):

From http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,samples.aspx#sample7 and http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,samples.aspx#sample6

```
Player pl = new Player();
byte[] arr = File.ReadAllBytes(@"in.wav");
pl.Play(arr);
Player pl2 = new Player();
pl2.FileName = "123.mp3";
pl2.Play();
```

or mix audio data before playing [How to mix to mix two audio file..](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip77)

```
private void Mix(string outfile, string infile1, string infile2, int shiftSec)
{
    WaveReader wr1 = new WaveReader(File.OpenRead(infile1));
    WaveReader wr2 = new WaveReader(File.OpenRead(infile2));
    IntPtr format1 = wr1.ReadFormat();
    WaveFormat wf = AudioCompressionManager.GetWaveFormat(format1);
    WaveWriter ww = new WaveWriter(File.Create(outfile), AudioCompressionManager.FormatBytes(format1));
    byte[] data0 = wr1.ReadData(0, shiftSec);
    byte[] data1 = wr1.ReadData(shiftSec);
    byte[] data2 = wr2.ReadData();
    byte[] mixData = AudioCompressionManager.Mix(format1, data2, data1);
    ww.WriteData(data0);
    ww.WriteData(mixData);
    ww.Close();
    wr2.Close();
    wr1.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

Here is what worked:

Make sure you add references to PresentationCore and WindowsBase dlls.

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\me\source\repos\TacticalIslandSurvival\sounds\blazer rail.wav");
            player.PlayLooping();
     }

        private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            var p1 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
            p1.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\Users\me\source\repos\TacticalIslandSurvival\sounds\click.wav"));
            p1.Play();

        }
```