# Thread doesn't run in background

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, xna

I am trying to play a sound in a new thread, so that other sounds don't interrupt it, while it is playing.

But it doesn't work. Although the new thread runs in background (I assume), the sounds which are played afterwards interrupt it.

```
ParameterizedThreadStart pts;
        Thread t;

private void playStreak(Object p)
        {
            SoundEffect sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("SOUNDFX/BOMB.wav", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
            SoundEffectInstance instance = sound.CreateInstance();
            instance.Play();
        }

private void playAsThread()
{
     pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(playStreak);
     t = new Thread(pts);
     t.Name = "Streak sound!";
     t.Start();
}
```

I want to play various sounds without interrupting each other.

Comment: Dis you read this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240002/play-two-sounds-simultaneusly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to use threads. You can have 16 SoundEffectInstances at one moment. Isn't it enough?

Check [this example](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=207868).

They just hold three `SoundEffect` instances.

```
    private SoundEffect coyoteSound;
    private SoundEffect birdSound;
    private SoundEffect ambienceSound;
```

and play them by some event.

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to use thread, use [BackgroundWorker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker). It's nice and easy!