# how to play multiple sound at same time in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

When i click a button, 1st sound plays and I need 2nd sound to play when i click another button as 1st sound is playing without having need to wait for 1st sound to stop. Sound 1 and sound2 should play overlapped In c# for windows 8.1 in visual studio 13

Comment: Have you considered threads ?

Comment: This question answers yours also.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240002/play-two-sounds-simultaneusly