# Play Sounds in a Visual Studio Application

Tags: c#, audio, visual-studio-2015, playback

I'm making a program in Visual Studio 2015 (C#) and I want to add sound effects to it. However, I have looked up countless tutorials but none of them seem to work, and gave me tons of errors. If anyone can give me a code to play a .wav file from resource files then I would be very grateful

Comment: [use this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6241374/4767498). you can also play multiple sounds together.

Comment: WinForms?  WPF?...something else?

Comment: Yes it says .wav in the question :)

Comment: ".wav" doesn't help.  I was asking about the **type of application** you are writing; not the format of the sound file...

Comment: Sorry, that was a reply to a previous comment which has now been deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**How to: Play Sounds in an Application**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383890%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Add the following method code under the button1_Click event hander :

```
 System.Media.SoundPlayer player = 
 new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
 player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\xxxx.wav";
 player.Load();
 player.Play();
```

Comment: if you set a proper path 100% output is assured..please go through the msdn reference..try to find the logic and dont run behind output alone :)

Comment: Finally Worked :) Thanks

Comment: Very happy to hear for your efforts that paid off :)

Answer (score 0):

If the file you want to play is wav files, try this.

```
var player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("c:\\tes.wav");
player.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

For myself I wrote this SounceController, hope it help:

```
using System.Windows.Media; // add reference to system.windows.presentation.
using System;
using System.IO;
public class SoundController
{
    private bool isPlaying;
    private MediaPlayer player;

    public SoundController()
    {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
    }
    ~SoundController()
    {
        player = null;
    }

    public void Play(string path)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path) || isPlaying)
            return;

        isPlaying = true;

        player.Open(new Uri(path));
        player.Play();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        if (isPlaying)
        {
            isPlaying = false;
            player.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.Windows.Presentation? Also you need System and IO namespaces. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Catquatwa Please describe the errors you are having. It's going to be really difficult to offer an error free code without even seeing a sample of your code, or the problems you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use PInvoke To play sound using winmm.dll

first of all import `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace in to your project.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Then in your class you will have

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
static extern Int32 mciSendString(string command, StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize, IntPtr hwndCallback);

public void Play(string path ,string name)
{
     // Open
     mciSendString($@"open {path} type waveaudio alias {name}", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
     // Play
     mciSendString($@"play {name}", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
 }
```

You can play the sound sending correct path of wave file with name. . given name does not need to be the same name of wave file.for example:

```
Play(@"C:\soundeffect.wav", "soundEffect1");
```

Usually sound effects are played simultaneously. you can call this method several times to play several files simultaneously.

```
Play(@"C:\soundeffect1.wav", "soundEffect1");
Play(@"C:\soundeffect2.wav", "soundEffect2");
Play(@"C:\soundeffect3.wav", "soundEffect3");
```