# How to stop thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2017

Info: I'm creating game using C# in Visual Studio 2017

How can I stop music thread? Is it possible even from different form?
I used this code to create thread which plays music in background

```
MediaPlayer bg;

public void main()
{
    IntializeComponent();
    Bg_music();
}

private void Bg_music()
{
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        bg = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
        bg.Open(new System.Uri(path + "Foniqz_-_Spectrum_Subdiffusion_Mix_real.wav"));
        bg.Play();
    }).Start();                        
}
```

When I try to stop the thread using this code, it stops window which is currently open and music/thread keeps playing music

```
bg.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    bg.Close();
});
```

also this didn't work

```
bg.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    bg.Stop();
});
```

Comment: First things first, don't use threads anymore, these have been superseeded by TPL `Task`. `Task` have numerous benefits and improvements on managing the `Thread` yourself.

Comment: Why is it in a separate thread to begin with? Removing the thread will simplify the code, and possibly also solve the issue at hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I abort/cancel TPL Tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783865/how-do-i-abort-cancel-tpl-tasks)

Comment: Don't use a thread at all. `Play()` won't block the UI

Comment: I'm guessing @Flater (as this is a game) so that it doesn't lock the UI thread

Comment: @Liam: Why is a task needed at all here? Media players inherently don't block the UI.

Comment: Not sure, I'm just saying that why I guess the OP is using a thread here. I don't write games...

Comment: @Liam: Why tell OP to use tasks if you don't know why they are needed in the first place? It seems like you're blindly pasting a "convert threads to tasks!" comment before even checking if it's applicable to the question at hand.

Comment: @Miicat What are you trying to do? `Play()` won't block and you are better of using the MediaPlayerElement tag anyway. Check [Play audio and video with MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer) tag anyway

Comment: There is literally no need to use `Thread` anymore. They're just harder to use. `Task` is just better (always)

Comment: @Liam Play doesn't block. No tasks are needed. The question is a bit ... unclear

Comment: Looking though OPs question history it seems they are using a thread because [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240002/play-two-sounds-simultaneusly). Probably worth pointing out that the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6241289/542251) on that is 7 years old! A lot has changed since 2011.

Comment: @Liam  And the author states: *This code demonstrates the two sounds playing on separate threads on top of each other, which is sort of pointless since the playback doesn't block anyway*

Comment: Just don't use a thread at all.  Your `bg` variable needs to be a field of the class instead of a local variable so you can simply call its Stop() and/or Close() method.  Do note that MediaPlayer is not in general good enough in game programming.  Okay for plain song playback but it does not have a decent way to mix sound effects.  Lots of libraries out there, Bass tends to get mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really need a background thread (because the MediaPlayer it's non-blocking on WPF) you may want to use one of the following paths in C#:

1. Use Cancelation Token & Tasks:

   ```
       MediaPlayer bg;
   readonly CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       Bg_music();
   }

   private void Bg_music()
   {

       Task.Run(() =>
       {
           bg = new MediaPlayer();
           bg.Open(new Uri(@"D:\Songs\201145-Made_In_England__Elton_John__320.mp3"));
           bg.Play();
           bg.Play();
           while (true)
           {
               if (tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                   bg.Stop();
                   break;
               }
           }

       }, tokenSource.Token);

   }

   private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
          tokenSource.Cancel();
   }
   ```

   }

or

2. Use Events to communicate through Tasks. (Stop using threads, we have tasks now)

Comment: Will it continue playing music, if other sound is played at the same time/simultaneously? Here's link to the code how I first solved how to play two sounds simultaneously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50425310/how-i-can-play-two-sounds-simultaneously-in-c-sharp

Comment: How I can stop it from other form?

Answer (score -1):

Cross-thread object access might be tricky.

Once you create `MediaPlayer` instance in another thread other than the UI thread, accessing this object inside the UI thread will throw `InvalidOperationException` since the object doesn't belong to UI thread.

```
    private void Bg_music()
    {
        bg = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
        new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            bg.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{
                bg.Open(new System.Uri(path + "Foniqz_-_Spectrum_Subdiffusion_Mix_real.wav"));
                bg.Play();
            });

        }).Start();                        
    }
```

Now you don't have to use `Dispatcher` to stop the `MediaPlayer` when calling it inside the UI thread.

Edit: Even if the implemented method is not the best practice, still worth to be answered to advert some theorical information.